# Go Programming Language - System Time

Tags: go

Can anybody help me by answering how to get system time in GO. For example, in the below code, I want to know when the first print and second print statements are executed and what is the time difference between them.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
    fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the `time` package. Documentation can be found at http://golang.org/pkg/time/

For getting the nanoseconds-time before, after the first and after the last of your statements, and then printing them out:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
  i1 := time.Nanoseconds();
  fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
  i2 := time.Nanoseconds();
  fmt.Println("Hello, 世界")
  i3 := time.Nanoseconds();
  fmt.Println("Check this out!")
  fmt.Println(i1)
  fmt.Println(i2)
  fmt.Println(i3)
  fmt.Println(time.NanosecondsToLocalTime(i1).Format(time.StampNano))
  fmt.Println(time.NanosecondsToLocalTime(i2).Format(time.StampNano))
  fmt.Println(time.NanosecondsToLocalTime(i3).Format(time.StampNano))
}
```

In my VM, I then get the following results:

```
~/dev/go/test $ nano test.go
~/dev/go/test $ 6g test.go; 
~/dev/go/test $ 6l test.6
~/dev/go/test $ ./6.out
Hello, 世界
Hello, 世界
Check this out!
1322386593830456000
1322386593830498000
1322386593830501000
Nov 27 10:36:33.830456000
Nov 27 10:36:33.830498000
Nov 27 10:36:33.830501000
```

Answer (score 1):

See the `time` package. http://golang.org/pkg/time/